# how to login in ec2 instance for which i have set the password and I couldn't able to login. Now how can i recover that instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have enabled PAM in sshd_config in my ec2 instance and now I couldn't able to login to that server. How can I recover that instance?